# what is the advantage of an HTTP server serving database data dynamically in an HTML table vs one that serves the same data in JSON format?

Tags: html, json

i am just starting with this topic to study about it and hopefully be able to also programm deifferent stuff on the web . but for now i was wondering if a server serving data dinamically in an html table has any advantage over the same thing but in json format or the other way around. Thanks in advance!

Comment: HTML tables are for humans to read; JSON is generally not.

Comment: depends on your usage. I find it much cleaner to do an AJAX request for JSON data and parse on retrieval.. We use both methods at my work... JSON is much cleaner..